# How to pass layout to vue component with setup script

Tags: typescript, vue.js, installation, vue-component, vuejs3

`LayoutComponent`

```html
    <template>
      //some code here ...
      <div>
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </template>
```

In composition api you can pass a a layout by importing it and passing it into the layout option of `defineComponent`

```js
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from 'vue'
import LayoutComponent from '@/path/to/component'
           ☝️
export default defineComponent({
  layout: LayoutComponent
  //...        ☝️
```

What would be the equivalent of this in a setup script?
Thank you in advance :)

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import LayoutComponent from '@/path/to/component
// ???
```

Answer (score 2):

I realized that you can wrap the entire component with the layout component.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import LayoutComponet form '@/path/to/component'
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <LayoutComponent>
    <p>Component wrapped in a layout</p>
  </LayoutComponent>
</template>
```

I don't delete this question in case someone finds this useful :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it, since I've tried it and in the Vue DevTools I still see that the LayoutComponent is a child of that component. The thing I guess you want is make that component to be a child of the Layout, not the opposite. Idk how to do it though.